# Why is my spiral water pump not working as expected?

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

I made a very simple water pump: it's just a spiral inside of a tube. It rotates and is supposed to transport the fluid up (like on those children's playgrounds where you rotate exactly such a thing to pump water up) but it's completely not working, as you can see, the water splatters around everywhere!

The spiral rotates via keyframe animation so that shouldn't be the problem. The tube has Volume Initialization set to "Shell". I tried the other options too.

All objects have their neccessary fluid settings and stuff, I also baked it correctly. There must be something i'm missing, can anyone help me out?

(Also the spiral is rotating correctly. It just doesn't look like it in the 2 images below)

Begin:
[image: begin]
End:
[image: end]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: @RickT Thanks I didn't know that, i uploaded it, see question edit

Comment: Does such a "spiral pump" really work in real? The spiral is more like a drill than a water pump. With it, you can probably transport stones, clays, and possibly sand. But liquids will immediately flow back because of gravity if the spiral does not rotate at a very high speed. Some kind of shovel or trowel is missing to transport the water, isn't it?

Comment: nevermind. The trick is not to sink the lower end completely into the water so that air and water alternately enter the screw. Here is an illustration of a so-called "screw pump": https://empoweringpumps.com/screw-pump-basics/

Comment: @Blunder Interesting… To my understanding the air has nothing to do with it (well, OK, without it the water would boil away, but if you imagine a magic liquid that can't boil or expand, it will still be transported up by the screw pump). I aligned a blue cylinder with a model of the screw, and used a boolean on the blue cylinder - if you imagine the blue cylinder to be water, part of this water is trapped in a local minimum and can't be pulled by gravity down the screw: https://i.imgur.com/vqY8BXm.png Does submerging entire end in water decrease the performance of the pump for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when you upload a file for troubleshooting it would be best to leave the settings like you used them - in your file, on the domain object *Liquid* is disabled, but this way no fluid will be simulated so I guess that's not the setting you used.

The next thing is, your *Resolution Divisions* at 32 are way too low. The size of the simulated voxels are calculated by `largest dimension of domain / resolution divisions` which in your scene is 22.5m/32 = 0.7m approximately, so your "water drops" are 70cm large. If you then take into account that the tube is less than 2m in diameter which results in less than 1m of space between tube wall and spiral going through the center - without even taking any of their thicknesses into account there is almost no room for the fluid to squeeze itself inside the tube. Especially not where the tube is intersecting with the bowl holding the water and is blocking even more space.

By the way, the small cube in the corner of the domain shows the voxel size according to the resolution divisions. As you can see, this is huge in relation to the scene setup. I would at least set the resolution to 100 or 150, better 200.

[image: resolution divisions]

Talking about walls and wall thickness: I don't know how you've created the spiral, but the geometry is twisted, leading to parts where it seems to be thin like a blade (which is not working really well with fluid simulations) and what is even worse, turning inside faces outwards. If you enable *Face Orientation* in the viewport *Overlays*, you can see that it's half blue, half red. Blue is good, these are the faces pointing in the correct direction. The red ones are inverted and thus are not effecting the fluid like they should. So with this object you will never get the water upwards. But I'm not going to model a new spiral for you.

[image: face orientation]

This is not an answer to make it work - therefore I would have to create a new spiral - but these are some hints on which parts you have to work and if you have good geometry on your models (and avoid intersections like the bowl going inside the tube) and a higher resolution and it is still not working, we can have a closer look what's missing.

Comment: You can "noddle" a spiral with Geometry Nodes. *Kuboå* has shown a nice solution here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/255436/107598. To get the double helix DNA design just rotate the first spiral by 180° and add a *Solidify* modifier: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSFmU.jpg

Comment: @Blunder Maybe you should tag the OP to make sure he reads this explanation. Or was it meant for me? I would know ways to get a spiral, but I don't think I want to model the scene setup for the OP.

Comment: Oh, I thought the OP always gets a notification. -- Do you, @Squareoot? ;-)

Comment: @Blunder Of comments under the question yes, as well as the author of an answer under his answer... but I'm not yet sure if the OP gets notified of comments under other's answers (I usually don't ask questions so I haven't lots of experience with this).

Comment: It looks like the shape of this screw will not capture and carry any water up. Either the shape is bad or the angle is too steep. 

Comment: Correct shape/angle of the screw: https://i.imgur.com/5wS4B2V.png

Comment: Thank you so much, this was extremely helpful!! I will think of all those things. Great answer!